# Django query does not group

Tags: python, django

I want to group the number of messages by recipient user -> {'User 1': 5};{'User 2': 7}...

My model:

```
class Mensaje(models.Model):
    remitente = models.ForeignKey('Usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Remitente')
    destinatario = models.ForeignKey('Usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Destinatario')
    mensaje = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(1000)]) 
    leido = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fechaEnvio = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My query:

```
 mensajes = Mensaje.objects.filter(destinatario=request.user).values('pk', 'remitente__username').annotate(num_msg=Count('pk')).order_by('-fechaEnvio')
```

Result:

```
{'pk': 28, 'remitente__username': 'Paco', 'num_msg': 1}, {'pk': 27, 'remitente__username': 'Paco', 'num_msg': 1}, {'pk': 26, 'remitente__username': 'jota', 'num_msg': 1}, {'pk': 25, 'remitente__username': 'jota', 'num_msg': 1}...
```

As you can see, the query returns all the messages without group by user.

Another question:
Why does not work `mensajes = request.user.mensaje_set.all()`?

Comment: Given that each primary key `pk` is unique, it seems it's properly grouped by. Perhaps you need to remove the `pk` and just select, and count, the username to group by duplicates?

Comment: That does not work

Comment: Drop the `order_by` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = Mensaje.objects.values('remitente__username').annotate(num_msg=Count('pk')).order_by('remitente__username')
```

You did order_by as `.order_by('-fechaEnvio')` which has no logic in this context. ( You are trying to ordering a Table with an attribute (`fechaEnvio`), which is not belongs to the newly generated group_by table)

Answer (score 0):

You're grouping but the message id instead of the user id. To group by the recipient's user id you would have to do `.values('remitente__pk')`